# Firehol rules with kernel modules for MPD

Tags: iptables, kernel-module, mpd

Note: firehol uses iptables, so perhaps you do not have to know firehol to answer my question.

I am stuck with adjusting my firehol.conf to allow connections from outside to an MPD server (https://www.musicpd.org/) running on my machine. This is the part from the config which concerns MPD (inspired by https://firehol.org/guides/adding-services/):

```
server_mpd_ports="tcp/6600 udp/6600"
client_mpd_ports="any"
require_mpd_modules="ip_conntrack"

interface46 any world
        policy drop

        server mpd accept
```

Especially with the line
    *require_mpd_modules="ip_conntrack"*
I am unsure. I have no idea how these modules work tbh..

The ip address and port are set to default in the mpd.conf. Still running *mpc --host=....* from another machine in the network results in a dropped connection.

Perhaps anyone has a working firehol.conf for MPD, so that I can compare to my own to find the errors?

Answer (score 0):

Lol, a restart of the machine solved it. Working firehol.conf:

```
server_mpd_ports="tcp/6600"
client_mpd_ports="any"

interface46 any world
        policy drop

        server mpd accept
```